# Pair multiple response sets in SPSS for their direct comparison

Tags: spss

In my database, I have 5 multiple dichotomy sets `MRST1 to MRST5` (already defined by MRSETS command); where each of the sets consists from the same list of items (`item 1 to 10`) although from different variables (`v1 to v50`).

And I want to create a table with direct comparison of the column percentages in such a way that I have the sets in columns (MRST1 to MRST5) and their items (item 1 to 10) in rows.

Already tried using `MULT RESPONSE` and `MRSETS` but these do not allow for "item pairing" as far as documentations explains; I've also used `CTABLES` and `CROSSTABS` with no success...

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the multiple sets definitions, you can get the table you want through some restructure:

```
varstocases 
    /make grp1 from v1 to v10
    /make grp2 from v11 to v20
    /make grp3 from v21 to v30
    /make grp4 from v31 to v40
    /make grp5 from v41 to v50/index=vr(grp1)/null=keep.
means grp1 to grp5 by vr/cells=mean.
```

Comment: Tbh, I expected a solution that would not require transforming the database. Anyway, this works well and solves the task. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: I can't say that a solution like that doesn't exist - don't use custom tables myself - but if a few lines of code get you there easily enough....